# Changing "tag wiki suggested edit was approved"

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki, tag-excerpt

Whenever I edit a tag wiki and its excerpt, I see a notification after sometime(after it was approved) like this

[image: notification]

That should change it something like
"[some-tag] tag wiki suggested edit approved" or if it was an excerpt that was edited,then "[some-tag] tag excerpt suggested edit approved".

Otherwise there is no way to know whether the excerpt was approved or the wiki was without clicking on the notification. We should at least know the edit of which tag wiki/excerpt was approved..This should be changed in [the reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3049655/cool-guy?tab=reputation) in the profile page too. Here is a screenshot of it when I edited the wiki and excerpt of two tags:
[image: my rep tab]

I've just noticed that the "reputation" in [the summary tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3049655/cool-guy?tab=summary) of the profile page shows what I want. 
[image: the reputation in the summary tab]

Why doesn't the achievements tab at the top and the reputation tab show it then?